# 1440p 144hz monitor stuck at 60hz

Tags: intel-graphics, display-resolution, hdmi, monitor

I have a 1440p 144hz monitor connected to my system via HDMI. My CPU is an intel i5 10400 in an ROG Strix z490i motherboard. I don't have a dedicated graphics card so I am just running off of integrated graphics. My motherboard supports HDMI 2.0 and I am pretty sure that I am using an HDMI 2.0 capable cable. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Kernel 6.2.9 installed.

In my display settings, the refresh rate is listed as 59.95hz and I have no option to change this. Before on a 1080p 144hz monitor it only let me go up to 120hz max. I have tried running `xrandr --rate 144` and I get the output `Rate 144.00 Hz not available for this size`. I get the same output trying `xrandr --rate 60`.

As far as I understand, hHDMI 2.0 support 1440p to at least 120hz and support 1080p at 240hz, so I am not sure why I don't have the option to increase my refresh rate. Intel UHD graphics 630 should support this refresh rate as well. I am new to linux so I'm not sure if there is something that I'm missing. Please help me fix this.

Comment: You are using an untested kernel. So the driver in that kernel may be a problem. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I was having the same issue on the fresh install of Ubuntu, I tried updating kernel to see if that resolved the issue.